# How to store 5 integers numbers entered by the user in an array and print out this whole array?

Tags: c++

I tried to store the 5 integers entered by the user in an array using this code:

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    cin >> x;

}
 int a[5] = {x} ;
```

okay now I equaled the 5 integers numbers entered by the user to an array that has 5 digits 
When I tried to print this array using this code :

```
    for (int j = 0 ; j<5 ; j++) {
    cout << "/" <<a[j]  ;
}
```

it just printed the last number not the whole array like if the user entered 
1 
2
3
4
5 
it will print 5/0/0/0/0, How can I print like the user entered 1/2/3/4/5?

Comment: `int arr[5]; for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) std::cin >> arr[i]; for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) std::cout << arr[i] << " "; std::cout << "\n";`

Comment: It looks like you're not assigning values to the 5 slots in the `a` array.  Try doing the assignment inside your for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overriding the same variable when you input the numbers. Instead, you could input them directly to the array's elements:

```
int a[5];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
}
```